# Get current enum value based number of iterations

Tags: c#

I have enum defined as such

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    South = 0,
    East = 1,
    North = 2,
    West = 3,
}
```

How can I get current enum value after X iterations if I know my initial enum value?

E.g. if initial is South then

1. iteration => South
2. iteration => East
3. iteration => West
4. iteration => South
5. iteration => East

etc...

E.g. if initial is West then

1. iteration => West
2. iteration => South
3. iteration => East
4. iteration => North

etc...

Comment: `(CurrentValue + NumIterations - 1) % 4`

Comment: @mjwills - and a cast to `MyEnum`

Comment: Probably you'll need to do some cast to `int` and to `MyEnum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for modular arithmetic. The enum at iteration `x` (0-based) starting with the value `e`, can be calculated with this formula:

```
var result = (MyEnum)(((int)e + x) % 4);
```

You can replace `4` with however many values your enum has.